# ECN mark in ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

### `Requirements`

I have two Ubuntu machines and I want to `ECN` mark all packets coming out of the first one and detect it in another machine.

### `Attempt`

I modified `en-queue` of `sch_tbf.c` (qdisc) and added `INET_ECN_set_ce`(skb);

I can see inside machine 1 (generator) that `ECN` is set, but when packets reach the other machine, this mark is disappeared (`tos=0`).

I was wondering if anyone could help me in implementing this.I enabled forwarding and I see packets reach the second one.I also enabled `ECN` using `proc`.